# Accessing the propery bag from an elements.xml file

Tags: ribbon, custom-actions, property

I want to access some configuration data stored in the property bag. I want to access this information from a elements.xml file. This elements.xml file contains a Ribbon with Tabs and Buttons. Is there a way to do this? Or a way to access a static public string from an elements.xml file?

The Ribbon and its child controls are all inside a  element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in then xml, but when you create ribbon buttons you specify javascript to execute when clicked.

You then have two options:

1. Use Client Object Model in this javascript to retrieve the property and do the navigation
2. Navigate to a trampolin page which reads the property and redirects

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to access the object model in that way from a static XML file. You'd need code to pull the property you're referring to.

Comment: I can pull the property via code, and store it in a public string. Is there anyway to access that string from the xml file?

Comment: XML is markup... it can't pull dynamic values.

Comment: What if it was a public static string that was setup on PreLoad or something like that? Before the control got rendered the string would already be populated with the correct property value.

Comment: There's no such thing as a variable or a placeholder for the XML. Short of having something else generate the entire elements.xml file, I don't believe what you're doing is possible. Even considering that the elements.xml file is a static file stored within the solution and 14 hive, I'm not sure how you'd accomplish this. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I had part of a url stored in the property bag. I also have a ribbon with buttons. When a user clicks one of the buttons, it is supposed to go to a certain url stored in the property bag. I have the buttons declared through xml rather than code behind. I would like to set the buttons commanduihandler to the url stored in the property bag.

Comment: "a ribbon with buttons"... are you referring to the SharePoint ribbon, or some custom solution? I don't know of a way you can accomplish this with purely the XML, there's no way for the elements file to load/reference any dynamic values. Seems like you need code behind or a custom user control to handle this.

Comment: Yes a SharePoint ribbon with two tabs, each tab has about four buttons.